# Color dots bases on their values - vue - javascript

Tags: javascript, database, vue.js

I have created a table from a database. One of the columns called value. 
Instead of displaying the value. I am trying to display color dots based on a range. 
For example, value is zero or 0.5 then the color of the dot is red. If the value is between 1 and 3 then the color is orange.
If the value is greater then 3 the dot is colored green.

At the moment I got the following error: 
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.range is not a function"

It's probably something about how if define my function. And the type of data, I gave to my function.
I don't understand what the problem is. Could someone help me? Thanks a lot;

## Part of my vue code to display the value column

```
                   <template slot="value" slot-scope="row">
                        <span class="green dot" v-if="range(row.item.value) == 2"></span>
                        <span class="orange dot" v-if="range(row.item.value) == 1"></span>
                        <span class="red dot" v-if="range(row.item.value) == 1"></span>
                    </template>
```

## Part of my javascript code

```
export default {
    props: ['dbdata'],
    data() {
        return {
            dbs: this.dbdata,
            dbSearch: '',
            totalRows: 1,
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 10,
            pageOptions: [10, 20, 50,100],
            sortBy: "id",
            sortDesc: false,
            sortDirection: 'asc',
            filter: null,
            selectMode: 'multi',
            selected: [],
            fields: {
                id: {
                    label: "Id",
                    sortable: true
                },
                name: {
                    label: "Name",
                    sortable: true
                },
                value: {
                    label: "value",
                    sortable: true
                }                    
            }
        } 
    },
            computed:{ 
        hits: function(){
            var hits = this.dbs.length
            return hits
        },
        range: function(x){
            if (x < 1){
                x = 0;
            }if(x >= 1 && x <= 3 ){
                x = 1;
            }if(x >= 3 ){
                x = 2;
            }
            return x
        }

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods should be in the methods property:

```
computed: { 
    hits: function(){
        var hits = this.dbs.length
        return hits
    },
}
methods: {
    range: function(x){
        if (x < 1){
            x = 0;
        }if(x >= 1 && x <= 3 ){
            x = 1;
        }if(x >= 3 ){
            x = 2;
        }
        return x
    }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers

Instead of using the v-if in this case, maybe you could use the css property to add the correct color. Try create a function that return the color as string and pass it to the :class property:

```
<template slot="value" slot-scope="row">
  <span class="dot" :class="color" />
</template>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

I hope that maked sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a **computed property**, which doesn't accept an argument.
What you have to use is a basic **method** like this :

```
methods: {
  range(x) {
    if (x < 1) {
      x = 0;
    } if(x >= 1 && x <= 3 ) {
      x = 1;
    } if(x >= 3 ) {
      x = 2;
    }
    return x
  }
}
```

Now you can use your method in your template.

Answer (score 0):

After your help I found the following.

The vue code

```
    <template slot="value" slot-scope="row">
                        <span class='dot largerSize' :class="statusColor[range(row.item.value)]"></span>
    </template>
```

## Part of my javascript code

```
              range: function(x){
            if (x < this.min){
                return 0;
            }else if(x >= this.min && x <= this.max ){
                return 1;
            }else if(x >= this.max ){
                return 2;
            }
        }
```